# how to send data from component.ts file to service.ts file

Tags: angular

in the bookcomponent;

```
     addBookToBasket(id: string) {
     this.authService.user.subscribe((user) => {
      this.auth_id = user.id;
     });
     let detail: { count: number; updated: string }[]=[];

    this.basketService.getBasketById(this.auth_id).subscribe((res) => {
      Object.entries(res).map((book) => {
        if (id === book[1].book_id) {
          detail["count"]=book[1].count+1
          detail["updated"]=book[0]
        }
      });
    });
    console.log({detail});
    this.bookService
      .addBookToBasket({
        detail:detail
      })
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.alertService.toastAlert("success");
      });
  }
```

when I print the detail to the console, I access that the value has arrived and I am sending the details to this.bookService.addBookToBasket

in the BookService ;

```
  addBookToBasket(basket: MyBasket): Observable<MyBasket> {
    let tempUrl = this.firebase_url + "baskets/" + basket.user_id;
    console.log(basket.detail);
```

but this detail information comes undefined on the console in the addBookToBasket function

where am i doing wrong?

how do to access the value of the detail from the addBookToBasket function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not waiting the the asynchronous `getBasketById` function to complete before calling the `this.bookService.addBookToBasket` function. Try moving the `this.bookService.addBookToBasket` function call inside the `subscribe` function of the `getBasketById` call result:

```
this.basketService.getBasketById(this.auth_id).subscribe((res) => {
      Object.entries(res).map((book) => {
        if (id === book[1].book_id) {
          detail["count"]=book[1].count+1
          detail["updated"]=book[0]
        }

        console.log({detail});
        this.bookService.addBookToBasket({
          detail:detail
        })
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.alertService.toastAlert("success");
        });
      });
    });
```